# box2d world step never returns (game freezes)

Tags: android, libgdx, box2d

I'm developing a game with libgdx version 1.9.8 using box2d and Android Studio.

https://github.com/agmCorp/GameThree

My game is about a character who is moving up on the screen, shooting enemies (typical "shoot them all" game).
The camera is always moving upwards (my game is a Top-Down-View game) and I'm using Box2d to manage collisions detection.
I'm stuck in an error for weeks and I can't even begin to guess how to solve it.

My game freezes completely (the music keeps running but the graphics freeze on the screen), and of course doesn't respond to user events.

This error is always random, I haven't been able to determine its cause (I have to play my game for a while to reproduce it). I don't get any useful error, it just freezes!

Using debugging messages in my code, the game gets stuck when I do a world step (PlayScreen.java):

```
private static final float WORLD_TIME_STEP = 1/300.0f;
private static final int WORLD_VELOCITY_ITERATIONS = 6;
private static final int WORLD_POSITION_ITERATIONS = 2;

...

world.step(WORLD_TIME_STEP, WORLD_VELOCITY_ITERATIONS, WORLD_POSITION_ITERATIONS);
```

The programs executes that line, calling this method from libgdx, BUT NEVER RETURNS:

```
/** Take a time step. This performs collision detection, integration, and constraint solution.
 * @param timeStep the amount of time to simulate, this should not vary.
 * @param velocityIterations for the velocity constraint solver.
 * @param positionIterations for the position constraint solver. */
public void step (float timeStep, int velocityIterations, int positionIterations) {
    jniStep(addr, timeStep, velocityIterations, positionIterations);
}
```

I'm completely lost. What the problem could be?
It's a complete freeze, not a stutter, and a thread dump shows it is in the jniStep method (uy.com.agm.gamethree is my game):

```
03-30 17:45:19.801 8699-8718/uy.com.agm.gamethree I/art: Starting a blocking GC Explicit
03-30 17:45:19.872 8699-8710/uy.com.agm.gamethree W/art: Suspending all threads took: 48.360ms
03-30 17:45:19.876 8699-8718/uy.com.agm.gamethree I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 153337(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 39% free, 9MB/16MB, paused 323us total 70.540ms
03-30 17:45:35.308 8699-8793/uy.com.agm.gamethree E/OpenGLRenderer:   saveGfxinfoFileDisabled enabled


Crash report:

                                               --------- beginning of crash
03-30 05:20:41.782 15643-16929/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x2600000002 in tid 16929 (GLThread 7573)

                                         [ 03-30 05:20:41.788  3103: 3103 W/         ]
                                         debuggerd: handling request: pid=15643 uid=10413 gid=10413 tid=16929
03-30 05:20:41.789 3282-3453/? I/AudioMixer: create resampler src 44100, 2, dst 48000, 2, q 8
03-30 05:20:41.789 3282-3453/? I/AudioMixer: create resampler src 44100, 2, dst 48000, 2, q 8
03-30 05:20:41.790 3282-3453/? D/SoundAliveResampler: [SoundAliveResampler] Init+++
03-30 05:20:41.790 3282-3453/? D/SoundAliveResampler: [SoundAliveResampler] Init+++
03-30 05:20:41.796 3282-3450/? D/AudioFlinger: mixer(0xf111b280) throttle end: throttle time(8)
03-30 05:20:41.841 3704-3931/? D/InputReader: Input event(4): value=0 when=74370654276000
03-30 05:20:41.841 3704-3931/? D/InputReader: Input event(4): value=0 when=74370654276000
03-30 05:20:41.841 3704-3931/? I/InputReader: Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=] when=74370654276000
03-30 05:20:41.842 3704-3930/? I/InputDispatcher: Delivering touch to (15643): action: 0x1, toolType: 1
03-30 05:20:41.876 3299-18031/? I/NuPlayerRenderer: kWhatPollingAudioStarted clock running played_out : 31599564 us, audio_out : 31594285 us, gap : 5279 us
03-30 05:20:41.876 3299-18031/? I/MediaClock: setPlaybackRate rate : 1.000000
03-30 05:20:42.005 19080-19080/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-30 05:20:42.006 19080-19080/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'samsung/heroltexx/herolte:7.0/NRD90M/G930FXXU2DRB7:user/release-keys'
03-30 05:20:42.006 19080-19080/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '8'
03-30 05:20:42.006 19080-19080/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
03-30 05:20:42.007 19080-19080/? A/DEBUG: pid: 15643, tid: 16929, name: GLThread 7573  >>> uy.com.agm.gamethree <<<
03-30 05:20:42.007 19080-19080/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x2600000002
03-30 05:20:42.007 19080-19080/? A/DEBUG:     x0   0000002600000002  x1   00000000000000b8  x2   00000078464ff180  x3   0000000000000002
03-30 05:20:42.007 19080-19080/? A/DEBUG:     x4   0000000000000001  x5   0000000000000001  x6   0000000000000000  x7   0000000000000000
03-30 05:20:42.007 19080-19080/? A/DEBUG:     x8   0000007864aa1098  x9   0000000000000000  x10  0000000000000001  x11  0000000000000001
03-30 05:20:42.007 19080-19080/? A/DEBUG:     x12  000000786af11df8  x13  000000786af11e94  x14  000000788c2a5e50  x15  0000000000000000
03-30 05:20:42.007 19080-19080/? A/DEBUG:     x16  0000007864aa0a18  x17  0000007864a729d8  x18  000000000000002e  x19  00000078464ff180
03-30 05:20:42.007 19080-19080/? A/DEBUG:     x20  000000786a5ec5b0  x21  00000078464ff1c0  x22  0000000000000006  x23  000000788b2bcad0
03-30 05:20:42.007 19080-19080/? A/DEBUG:     x24  0000000000000008  x25  4572cf0aa562048b  x26  000000786b761498  x27  4572cf0aa562048b
03-30 05:20:42.007 19080-19080/? A/DEBUG:     x28  000000786af11e90  x29  000000786af11db0  x30  0000007864a76004
03-30 05:20:42.007 19080-19080/? A/DEBUG:     sp   000000786af11d80  pc   0000007864a72a34  pstate 0000000080000000
03-30 05:20:42.010 3299-18031/? I/MediaClock: updateClock correction (30000).  gapTimeUs(244394), nowMediaUs(31757243), oldMediaUs(31512849)
03-30 05:20:42.027 19080-19080/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
03-30 05:20:42.027 19080-19080/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 000000000001ba34  /data/app/uy.com.agm.gamethree-1/lib/arm64/libgdx-box2d.so (_ZN16b2BlockAllocator8AllocateEi+92)
03-30 05:20:42.027 19080-19080/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 000000000001f000  /data/app/uy.com.agm.gamethree-1/lib/arm64/libgdx-box2d.so (_ZN7b2World10CreateBodyEPK9b2BodyDef+48)
03-30 05:20:42.028 19080-19080/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 000000000002f6d0  /data/app/uy.com.agm.gamethree-1/lib/arm64/libgdx-box2d.so (Java_com_badlogic_gdx_physics_box2d_World_jniCreateBody+160)
03-30 05:20:42.028 19080-19080/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 00000000000db490  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+144)
03-30 05:20:42.028 19080-19080/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0000000000049fb0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache_15643_15643 (deleted)
03-30 05:20:42.034 3299-18031/? I/MediaClock: updateClock correction (30000).  gapTimeUs(214368), nowMediaUs(31781229), oldMediaUs(31566861)
03-30 05:20:42.210 3282-3376/? I/APM_AudioPolicyManager: stopOutput() output 21, stream 3, session 42505
03-30 05:20:42.289 3299-18031/? I/MediaClock: updateClock correction (30000).  gapTimeUs(184390), nowMediaUs(32035616), oldMediaUs(31851226)
03-30 05:20:42.314 3299-18031/? I/MediaClock: updateClock correction (30000).  gapTimeUs(154402), nowMediaUs(32060515), oldMediaUs(31906113)
03-30 05:20:42.375 3704-3975/? D/WifiStateMachine: Current network is: "Alvaro" , ID is: 89
03-30 05:20:42.375 3704-3975/? D/WifiStateMachine: 24GHz mQnsLowerRssiThreshold is recovered, currentRssi = -49
03-30 05:20:42.392 4964-4964/? D/io_stats: !@   8,0 r 2694264 91924500 w 736624 13096768 d 102506 5500444 f 203857 203776 iot 1184890 1039063 th 303772 0 0 pt 0 inp 0 0 74371.205
03-30 05:20:42.570 3299-18031/? I/MediaClock: updateClock correction (30000).  gapTimeUs(124404), nowMediaUs(32316867), oldMediaUs(32192463)
03-30 05:20:42.837 3299-18031/? I/MediaClock: updateClock correction (30000).  gapTimeUs(94401), nowMediaUs(32584178), oldMediaUs(32489777)
03-30 05:20:42.909 3282-3376/? I/APM_AudioPolicyManager: stopOutput() output 21, stream 3, session 42513
03-30 05:20:43.422 3704-4635/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 2477 [2018-03-30 05:20:43.422]
03-30 05:20:43.560 3282-3376/? I/APM_AudioPolicyManager: stopOutput() output 21, stream 3, session 42521
03-30 05:20:43.561 3282-3376/? I/APM_AudioPolicyManager: stopOutput() output 21, stream 3, session 42529
03-30 05:20:43.619 3704-7729/? D/SSRM:f: SIOP:: AP = 410, PST = 415 (W:10), CP = 338, CUR = -416, LCD = 51

                                         [ 03-30 05:20:44.517 19080:19080 E/         ]
                                         ro.debug_level = 0x4f4c

                                         [ 03-30 05:20:44.517 19080:19080 E/         ]
                                         sys.mobilecare.preload = false
03-30 05:20:44.533 3252-3252/? E/audit: type=1701 audit(1522398044.525:4506): auid=4294967295 uid=10413 gid=10413 ses=4294967295 subj=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 pid=16929 comm=474C5468726561642037353733 exe="/system/bin/app_process64" sig=11
03-30 05:20:44.546 3704-19082/? W/DropBoxManagerService: Dropping: data_app_native_crash (1930 > 0 bytes)
03-30 05:20:44.549 3704-19081/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity uy.com.agm.gamethree/.AndroidLauncher

                                                   [ 03-30 05:20:44.549  3103: 3103 W/         ]
                                                   debuggerd: resuming target 15643
03-30 05:20:44.549 3704-19081/? W/MultiScreenManagerService: moveTaskBackToDisplayIfNeeded(): root is not base activity
03-30 05:20:44.554 3704-19081/? D/ActivityManager: moveToFront() : reason=finishActivity adjustFocus setFocusedActivity isAttached=true TaskRecord{6649fe3d0 #2 A=com.sec.android.app.launcher U=0 StackId=0 sz=1}
03-30 05:20:44.554 3704-19081/? W/MultiScreenManagerService: moveTaskBackToDisplayIfNeeded(): root activity or app is null
03-30 05:20:44.555 3704-3827/? I/BootReceiver: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_05 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
03-30 05:20:44.555 3704-19081/? D/ActivityManager: setFocusStackUnchecked: reason=finishActivity adjustFocus setFocusedActivity focusCandidate=ActivityStack{3331884d0 stackId=0, 2 tasks} caller=com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.moveToFront:875 com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.moveActivityStackToFront:1995 
03-30 05:20:44.563 3704-3827/? W/DropBoxManagerService: Dropping: SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE (10 > 0 bytes)
03-30 05:20:44.569 3704-19081/? D/InputDispatcher: Focused application set to: xxxx
03-30 05:20:44.570 3704-19081/? D/InputDispatcher: Focus left window: 15643
03-30 05:20:44.572 3704-19081/? D/ActivityTrigger: ActivityTrigger activityPauseTrigger 
03-30 05:20:44.572 3704-19081/? D/GameManagerService: sem_perfomance_mode: 0
03-30 05:20:44.598 3190-3190/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/15643/oom_score_adj; errno=22
03-30 05:20:44.640 3299-3825/? V/MediaPlayerService: Client(72) destructor pid = 15643
03-30 05:20:44.640 3299-3825/? V/MediaPlayerService: disconnect(72) from pid 15643
03-30 05:20:44.640 3299-3825/? D/NuPlayerDriver: reset(0xdd570c00) at state 8
03-30 05:20:44.641 3299-16939/? V/NuPlayer: kWhatReset
03-30 05:20:44.641 3299-16939/? V/NuPlayer: setDecoderBooster enable = No
03-30 05:20:44.641 3299-16939/? V/NuPlayer: performDecoderFlush audio=2, video=2
03-30 05:20:44.641 3299-16939/? V/NuPlayer: [audio] flushDecoder needShutdown=1
03-30 05:20:44.641 3299-16939/? V/NuPlayer: postponing action mFlushingAudio=2, mFlushingVideo=0
03-30 05:20:44.641 3299-16939/? V/NuPlayer: mResetInProgress=1, mVideoEOS =0, mAudioEOS =0
03-30 05:20:44.641 3299-16939/? V/NuPlayer: (mAudioDecoder != NULL) = true, (mVideoDecoder != NULL) = false
03-30 05:20:44.641 3704-3987/? D/GraphicsStats: Buffer count: 7
03-30 05:20:44.641 3704-8833/? D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=595
03-30 05:20:44.643 9906-9906/? D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=71
03-30 05:20:44.643 3299-16993/? I/NuPlayerRenderer: flush audio, notifyComplete 1
03-30 05:20:44.643 3299-16993/? D/NuPlayerRenderer: signalTimeDiscontinuity() mHasAudio = 1 , mHasVideo = 0
03-30 05:20:44.643 3299-16992/? I/NuPlayerRenderer: flushing audio
03-30 05:20:44.644 3299-16992/? I/NuPlayerRenderer: onFlush mAudioDrainGeneration : 4
03-30 05:20:44.644 3299-16992/? V/AudioSink: flush
03-30 05:20:44.644 3299-16994/? I/ACodec: [OMX.google.vorbis.decoder] signalFlush
03-30 05:20:44.644 3299-16994/? I/ACodec: [OMX.google.vorbis.decoder] ExecutingState flushing now (codec owns 4/4 input, 0/4 output).
03-30 05:20:44.645 3299-16994/? I/ACodec: [OMX.google.vorbis.decoder] Now Flushing
03-30 05:20:44.645 3299-16994/? I/ACodec: [OMX.google.vorbis.decoder] FlushingState onOMXEvent(0,1,0)
03-30 05:20:44.645 3299-16994/? I/ACodec: [OMX.google.vorbis.decoder] FlushingState onOMXEvent(0,1,1)
03-30 05:20:44.645 3299-16994/? I/ACodec: [OMX.google.vorbis.decoder] Now Executing
03-30 05:20:44.646 3299-16939/? V/NuPlayer: decoder audio flush completed
03-30 05:20:44.646 3299-16992/? V/AudioSink: stop
03-30 05:20:44.647 3299-16939/? V/NuPlayer: renderer audio flush completed.
03-30 05:20:44.647 3299-16939/? V/NuPlayer: initiating audio decoder shutdown
03-30 05:20:44.648 3299-16994/? I/ACodec: [OMX.google.vorbis.decoder] Now Executing->Idle
03-30 05:20:44.649 3704-3792/? I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{da8728d0 u0 SurfaceView - uy.com.agm.gamethree/uy.com.agm.gamethree.AndroidLauncher}
03-30 05:20:44.650 3704-3792/? I/WindowManager_SurfaceController: Destroying surface Surface(name=SurfaceView - uy.com.agm.gamethree/uy.com.agm.gamethree.AndroidLauncher) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2840 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:1070 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1783 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2893 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2854 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2839 com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied:2203 android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice:701 
03-30 05:20:44.651 3192-3939/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=1149 Removed BndroidLaun (2/5)
03-30 05:20:44.654 3192-9227/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=1149 Removed BndroidLaun (-2/5)
03-30 05:20:44.654 3192-3199/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=1150 Removed BndroidLaun (1/4)
03-30 05:20:44.655 3299-16994/? I/ACodec: [OMX.google.vorbis.decoder] Now Idle->Loaded
03-30 05:20:44.655 3192-3197/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=1150 Removed BndroidLaun (-2/4)
03-30 05:20:44.656 3299-16994/? I/ACodec: [OMX.google.vorbis.decoder] Now Loaded
03-30 05:20:44.659 3299-16994/? I/ACodec:  [OMX.google.vorbis.decoder] Now uninitialized
03-30 05:20:44.659 3299-16994/? I/ACodec:  [] Now kWhatShutdownCompleted event : 8362
03-30 05:20:44.659 3299-16994/? I/MediaCodec: Codec shutdown complete
03-30 05:20:44.660 3299-16993/? I/NuPlayerDecoder: onShutdown notifyComplete : Yes
03-30 05:20:44.660 3299-16939/? V/NuPlayer: audio shutdown completed
03-30 05:20:44.660 3299-16939/? W/AMessage: failed to post message as target looper for handler 0 is gone.
03-30 05:20:44.661 3299-16939/? V/NuPlayer: both audio and video are flushed now.
03-30 05:20:44.661 3299-16939/? V/NuPlayer: Reset was postponed execute processDeferredActions
03-30 05:20:44.662 3299-16939/? V/NuPlayer: performReset
03-30 05:20:44.662 3704-5446/? I/ActivityManager: Process uy.com.agm.gamethree (pid 15643) has died(78,1140)
03-30 05:20:44.662 3299-16939/? V/GenericSource: stop()
03-30 05:20:44.662 3299-16939/? V/GenericSource: PREPARE_CANCELLED set to true
03-30 05:20:44.662 3299-16939/? V/GenericSource: [Flag] set 0x40 -> mFlags = 0x48
03-30 05:20:44.662 3299-16939/? V/GenericSource: [Flag] clear 0x8 -> mFlags = 0x40
03-30 05:20:44.662 3299-16939/? V/GenericSource: stop() end
03-30 05:20:44.662 3299-16939/? V/GenericSource: ~GenericSource()
03-30 05:20:44.662 3704-5446/? D/ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 15643
03-30 05:20:44.663 3299-16939/? D/NuPlayerDriver: notifyResetComplete(0xdd570c00)
03-30 05:20:44.664 3299-3825/? V/NuPlayerDriver: ~NuPlayerDriver(0xdd570c00)
03-30 05:20:44.664 3298-18728/? I/OggExtractor: OggSource::stop() mExtractor ref count = 2
03-30 05:20:44.664 3298-18728/? I/OggExtractor: ~OggSource --
03-30 05:20:44.667 3299-3825/? V/AudioSink: +++ close
03-30 05:20:44.667 3299-3825/? V/AudioSink: --- close
03-30 05:20:44.668 3298-10317/? I/OggExtractor: ~OggExtractor ++
03-30 05:20:44.668 3298-10317/? I/OggExtractor: ~MyOggExtractor ++ 
03-30 05:20:44.668 3298-10317/? I/OggExtractor: ~MyOggExtractor --
03-30 05:20:44.668 3298-10317/? I/OggExtractor: ~OggExtractor --
03-30 05:20:44.674 3704-3715/? I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 163943(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 16(1104KB) LOS objects, 8% free, 72MB/79MB, paused 3.415ms total 118.714ms
03-30 05:20:44.676 3299-3825/? V/MediaPlayerService: Client(73) destructor pid = 15643
03-30 05:20:44.676 3299-3825/? V/MediaPlayerService: disconnect(73) from pid 15643
03-30 05:20:44.676 3299-3825/? D/NuPlayerDriver: reset(0xdd570300) at state 8
03-30 05:20:44.676 3299-16954/? V/NuPlayer: kWhatReset
03-30 05:20:44.676 3299-16954/? V/NuPlayer: setDecoderBooster enable = No
03-30 05:20:44.676 3299-16954/? V/NuPlayer: performDecoderFlush audio=2, video=2
03-30 05:20:44.676 3299-16954/? V/NuPlayer: [audio] flushDecoder needShutdown=1
03-30 05:20:44.676 3299-16954/? V/NuPlayer: postponing action mFlushingAudio=2, mFlushingVideo=0
03-30 05:20:44.676 3299-16954/? V/NuPlayer: mResetInProgress=1, mVideoEOS =0, mAudioEOS =0
03-30 05:20:44.676 3299-17034/? I/NuPlayerRenderer: flush audio, notifyComplete 1
03-30 05:20:44.676 3299-16954/? V/NuPlayer: (mAudioDecoder != NULL) = true, (mVideoDecoder != NULL) = false
03-30 05:20:44.676 3299-17034/? D/NuPlayerRenderer: signalTimeDiscontinuity() mHasAudio = 1 , mHasVideo = 0
03-30 05:20:44.676 3299-17033/? I/NuPlayerRenderer: flushing audio
03-30 05:20:44.676 3299-17035/? I/ACodec: [OMX.google.vorbis.decoder] signalFlush
03-30 05:20:44.677 3299-17033/? I/NuPlayerRenderer: onFlush mAudioDrainGeneration : 6
03-30 05:20:44.677 3299-17033/? V/AudioSink: flush
03-30 05:20:44.677 3299-17035/? I/ACodec: [OMX.google.vorbis.decoder] ExecutingState flushing now (codec owns 4/4 input, 0/4 output).
03-30 05:20:44.677 3299-17033/? V/AudioSink: stop
03-30 05:20:44.677 3299-17035/? I/ACodec: [OMX.google.vorbis.decoder] Now Flushing
03-30 05:20:44.678 3299-16954/? V/NuPlayer: renderer audio flush completed.
03-30 05:20:44.678 3299-17035/? I/ACodec: [OMX.google.vorbis.decoder] FlushingState onOMXEvent(0,1,0)
03-30 05:20:44.678 3299-17035/? I/ACodec: [OMX.google.vorbis.decoder] FlushingState onOMXEvent(0,1,1)
03-30 05:20:44.678 3299-17035/? I/ACodec: [OMX.google.vorbis.decoder] Now Executing
03-30 05:20:44.679 3299-16954/? V/NuPlayer: decoder audio flush completed
03-30 05:20:44.679 3704-3992/? I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{20488c5d0 u0 uy.com.agm.gamethree/uy.com.agm.gamethree.AndroidLauncher}
03-30 05:20:44.679 3299-16954/? V/NuPlayer: initiating audio decoder shutdown
03-30 05:20:44.679 3704-3992/? I/WindowManager_SurfaceController: Destroying surface Surface(name=uy.com.agm.gamethree/uy.com.agm.gamethree.AndroidLauncher) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2840 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:1070 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1783 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2893 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2854 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2839 com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied:2203 android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice:701 
03-30 05:20:44.680 3192-3199/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=1148 Removed BndroidLaun (1/3)
03-30 05:20:44.680 3299-17035/? I/ACodec: [OMX.google.vorbis.decoder] Now Executing->Idle
03-30 05:20:44.681 3192-3197/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=1148 Removed BndroidLaun (-2/3)
03-30 05:20:44.683 3704-3992/? D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=474
03-30 05:20:44.684 3704-3992/? D/PowerManagerService: [api] release WakeLock SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK        'WindowManager' ON_AFTER_RELEASE (uid=1000, pid=3704, ws=WorkSource{10413}) (uid=1000, pid=3704, ws=WorkSource{10413}, pkg=android, elapsedTime=629662) (0x0)
03-30 05:20:44.684 3704-3992/? D/PowerManagerService: [api] applyWakeLockFlagsOnReleaseLocked : userActivityNoUpdateLocked is called : SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK        'WindowManager' ON_AFTER_RELEASE (uid=1000, pid=3704, ws=WorkSource{10413}) (uid=1000, pid=3704, ws=WorkSource{10413}, pkg=android, elapsedTime=629662)
03-30 05:20:44.690 3299-17035/? I/ACodec: [OMX.google.vorbis.decoder] Now Idle->Loaded
03-30 05:20:44.690 3299-17035/? I/ACodec: [OMX.google.vorbis.decoder] Now Loaded
03-30 05:20:44.693 3704-5446/? D/ActivityManager: resumeTopActivityInnerLocked() : #0 prevTask=null next=ActivityRecord{779e647d0 u0 com.sec.android.app.launcher/.activities.LauncherActivity t2} mFocusedStack=ActivityStack{3331884d0 stackId=0, 2 tasks}
03-30 05:20:44.694 3299-17035/? I/ACodec:  [OMX.google.vorbis.decoder] Now uninitialized
03-30 05:20:44.694 3299-17035/? I/ACodec:  [] Now kWhatShutdownCompleted event : 8362
03-30 05:20:44.694 3299-17035/? I/MediaCodec: Codec shutdown complete
03-30 05:20:44.695 3299-17034/? I/NuPlayerDecoder: onShutdown notifyComplete : Yes
03-30 05:20:44.695 3299-16954/? V/NuPlayer: audio shutdown completed
03-30 05:20:44.695 3299-16954/? W/AMessage: failed to post message as target looper for handler 0 is gone.
03-30 05:20:44.696 3299-16954/? V/NuPlayer: both audio and video are flushed now.
03-30 05:20:44.696 3299-16954/? V/NuPlayer: Reset was postponed execute processDeferredActions
03-30 05:20:44.696 3299-16954/? V/NuPlayer: performReset
03-30 05:20:44.696 3299-16954/? V/GenericSource: stop()
03-30 05:20:44.696 3299-16954/? V/GenericSource: PREPARE_CANCELLED set to true
03-30 05:20:44.696 3299-16954/? V/GenericSource: [Flag] set 0x40 -> mFlags = 0x48
03-30 05:20:44.696 3299-16954/? V/GenericSource: [Flag] clear 0x8 -> mFlags = 0x40
03-30 05:20:44.696 3299-16954/? V/GenericSource: stop() end
03-30 05:20:44.696 3299-16954/? V/GenericSource: ~GenericSource()
03-30 05:20:44.697 3704-5446/? D/CustomFrequencyManagerService: acquireDVFSLockLocked : type : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1560000  uid : 1000  pid : 3704  pkgName : AMS_RESUME@CPU_MIN@7
03-30 05:20:44.697 3299-16954/? D/NuPlayerDriver: notifyResetComplete(0xdd570300)
03-30 05:20:44.697 3299-3825/? V/NuPlayerDriver: ~NuPlayerDriver(0xdd570300)
03-30 05:20:44.698 3298-10305/? I/OggExtractor: OggSource::stop() mExtractor ref count = 2
03-30 05:20:44.698 3298-10305/? I/OggExtractor: ~OggSource --
03-30 05:20:44.698 3299-3825/? V/AudioSink: +++ close
03-30 05:20:44.698 3299-3825/? V/AudioSink: --- close
03-30 05:20:44.699 3298-3357/? I/OggExtractor: ~OggExtractor ++
03-30 05:20:44.699 3298-3357/? I/OggExtractor: ~MyOggExtractor ++ 
03-30 05:20:44.699 3298-3357/? I/OggExtractor: ~MyOggExtractor --
03-30 05:20:44.699 3298-3357/? I/OggExtractor: ~OggExtractor --
03-30 05:20:44.699 3299-3825/? V/MediaPlayerService: Client(74) destructor pid = 15643
03-30 05:20:44.699 3299-3825/? V/MediaPlayerService: disconnect(74) from pid 15643
03-30 05:20:44.699 3299-3825/? D/NuPlayerDriver: reset(0xdd570480) at state 5
03-30 05:20:44.699 3299-3825/? D/NuPlayerDriver: notifyListener_l(0xdd570480), (8, 0, 0), loop setting(0, 1)
03-30 05:20:44.699 3299-16971/? V/NuPlayer: kWhatReset
03-30 05:20:44.699 3299-16971/? V/NuPlayer: setDecoderBooster enable = No
03-30 05:20:44.699 3299-16971/? V/NuPlayer: performDecoderFlush audio=2, video=2
03-30 05:20:44.699 3299-16971/? V/NuPlayer: [audio] flushDecoder needShutdown=1
03-30 05:20:44.699 3299-18032/? I/NuPlayerRenderer: flush audio, notifyComplete 1
03-30 05:20:44.699 3299-16971/? V/NuPlayer: postponing action mFlushingAudio=2, mFlushingVideo=0
03-30 05:20:44.699 3299-16971/? V/NuPlayer: mResetInProgress=1, mVideoEOS =0, mAudioEOS =0
03-30 05:20:44.699 3299-18032/? D/NuPlayerRenderer: signalTimeDiscontinuity() mHasAudio = 1 , mHasVideo = 0
03-30 05:20:44.699 3299-16971/? V/NuPlayer: (mAudioDecoder != NULL) = true, (mVideoDecoder != NULL) = false
03-30 05:20:44.699 3299-18031/? I/NuPlayerRenderer: flushing audio
03-30 05:20:44.700 3299-18031/? I/NuPlayerRenderer: onFlush mAudioDrainGeneration : 4
03-30 05:20:44.700 3299-18031/? V/AudioSink: pause
03-30 05:20:44.700 3299-18033/? I/ACodec: [OMX.google.vorbis.decoder] signalFlush
03-30 05:20:44.700 3299-18033/? I/ACodec: [OMX.google.vorbis.decoder] ExecutingState flushing now (codec owns 4/4 input, 0/4 output).
03-30 05:20:44.700 3299-18033/? I/ACodec: [OMX.google.vorbis.decoder] Now Flushing
03-30 05:20:44.701 3299-18033/? I/ACodec: [OMX.google.vorbis.decoder] FlushingState onOMXEvent(0,1,0)
03-30 05:20:44.701 3299-18033/? I/ACodec: [OMX.google.vorbis.decoder] FlushingState onOMXEvent(0,1,1)
03-30 05:20:44.701 3299-18033/? I/ACodec: [OMX.google.vorbis.decoder] Now Executing
03-30 05:20:44.701 3299-16971/? V/NuPlayer: decoder audio flush completed
03-30 05:20:44.704 3704-5446/? D/ActivityManager: mActivityResumeBooster.acquire()
03-30 05:20:44.712 3704-5446/? D/GameManagerService: sem_perfomance_mode: 0
03-30 05:20:44.712 3704-3704/? D/GameManagerService: NotifyRunnable. pkg: com.sec.android.app.launcher, type: 4, isMinimized: false, isTunableApp: false
```

Do you guys have a clue of what is happening? How can I face this?

Answer (score 0):

I had this similar problem. The frustrating part is that it occurs randomly.

I'm not sure of how your game is implemented but in mine, that the problem was from time step of the physics simulation.

Initially, it was fixed at 1/60f. The problem with this approach is variation of FPS especially on mobile devices.

My solution was to fix the time step using the approach presented by Glenn Fiedler http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

You can find the LibGDX implementation of the techniques here: http://saltares.com/blog/games/fixing-your-timestep-in-libgdx-and-box2d/